# How to argue that a positive solution of a elliptic problem is bounded? (Particular case)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\in\mathbf{R}^N$ an unbounded domain and $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline\Omega)$,  $u>0$ such that
$$\Delta u + f(u)=0, \ \ \ \mbox{em} \ \ \Omega,$$
where $f$ is a bounded lipschitz continuous function. Then $u$ is bounded.

I don't know where I can find this result, and I believe that this assumptions implies $\nabla u$ is bounded too. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a counterexample: $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: x>1\}$; $u(x,y)=x$; $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: Yes... you give the counter example, thanks. But, you know that this result is true to the first derivate? $|\nabla u|$ is bounded in this situation?

Comment: @JoséCarlos On the same domain, $u(x,y)=x^2$ and $f\equiv 2$ give an example with unbounded gradient.

Comment: Pavel thank you for the counter examples! Im going to search these estimates at least in bounded domains.

Comment: @JoséCarlos I think the key term for that is "Alexandrov-Bakelman-Pucci".